# Tripleboot windows7 and ubuntu and linux mint

Tags: 12.10

So... I have ubuntu 12.10 w/ windows 7 as dualbooted using grub. Not using wubi. Now! I wanna install linux mint. (14) How do i triple boot it?
This is answeared but the button broke so i cant say that the answear is good. FAIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless Linux Mint does something really weird it should just update GRUB automatically and you should end up with an extra option in the GRUB menu at startup.

If it should fail you can just boot from an ubuntu live-cd and reinstall GRUB

Comment: Okay, trying it. If grub fails, ill try that u said.